# JIRA downloads tons of files every time I create a plugin

Tags: maven, jira, jira-plugin

I am new to JIRA and maven.

Every time I create a new plugin using `atlas-create-jira-plugin`, it downloads tons of files which I believe it did once before.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's maven downloading the files it needs to build the plugin. After the first time you do it you should be able to use the -o option for offline and it won't download any more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i think Maven does not, except you delete ~/.m2 regularly. This is the default directory for artifacts.

But could you provide a stacktrace/logs about the downloads?